# Uploading an image with a custom "via" link on Facebook

Tags: facebook, hyperlink

I just uploaded a picture from my app to facebook. The picture is uploaded successfully but the problem is that when pic is loaded is say that.

```
Uploaded via xyz app
```

where xyz is my app name. xyz is a link actually but when I click on this link Page not found error is occurred. Is there any way that I can give my android app link so that when user clicks it he should be directed to android market. I have tried putting a link in bundle params but that doesn't works. It works only for feeds not for image uploads. Please tell if it is to be done thorough coding or through the dev panel of facebook.

Comment: You should be able to set that link in your control panel on Facebook.
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Comment: @Jawad Amjad Posting image working?

Comment: thanks man image is posting in albums not on wall :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link points to the app’s canvas page. If you don’t have one, set one up.

And no, there is no way of setting that link to an (external) target yourself while posting/uploading an image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet :

```
    JSONObject attachment = new JSONObject();
    try {
        attachment.put("message", "Messages");
        attachment.put("name", "Your Custom Text!");
        attachment.put("href", "http://www.google.com");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    parameters.putString("attachment", attachment.toString());
```

Where parameters is your Bundle

Comment: Show snapshot how it should come @JawadAmjad

Comment: How can I show snapshot? I have not succeded yet. All I want is when I upload an image on facebook from my app. It says "Uploaded via ABC APP"...where ABC APP is a link. I want my custom link so that whenever user clicks on "Uploaded Via Abc App" it should direct the user to that link I specified.